# How to draw Table with graph lines in the FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, graph, drawing, flowdocument

In my FlowDocument I would like to include a table filled with text and graph lines. Which approach would you recommend? I was thinking about attaching adorner to a table, but I could not accomplish attaching adorner over the whole table so far.

Here is sketch of something that I want to add to the document:

[image]

I'm using C# and .NET 4.0

Comment: pls check this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970909.aspx and this one also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747133.aspx#building_a_table_with_code

Comment: Hi, I have been reading those, I can create table allright, but I don't know how to draw over it (please see sketch I have added to the post). I would like to draw colored lines over the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is solved with Grid. Grid is very similair to Table, and it has no problem to contain a Canvas. Here you can see the sample image, and sample of getting the Grid with Canvas together into FlowDocument. You can create same flow document through code too:

[image: Table with multiple rows, columns and drawing in the cells.]

```
<FlowDocument PageWidth="600" MinPageWidth="600" PagePadding="0,0,0,0">
  <Section>
    <Paragraph>
      <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Background="#FFFFFFFF" Margin="0,5,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="140"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="460"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
          <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Canvas Background="#FFFFFFFF" Name="Canvas0" Width="460" Height="40" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
          <Rectangle Fill="#FFD3D3D3" Width="140" Height="40" Canvas.Left="160" Canvas.Top="0"/>
          <Rectangle Fill="#FFA9A9A9" Width="91" Height="40" Canvas.Left="188" Canvas.Top="0"/>
          <Ellipse Fill="#FF3E00C1" Width="7" Height="7" Canvas.Left="282.978417266187" Canvas.Top="6.5"/>
          <Ellipse Fill="#FF1D00E2" Width="7" Height="7" Canvas.Left="199.508" Canvas.Top="26.5"/>
          <Line X1="286.478417266187" Y1="10" X2="203.008" Y2="30" StrokeThickness="2">
            <Line.Stroke>
              <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF1D00E2" Offset="0"/>
                  <GradientStop Color="#FF3E00C1" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
              </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Line.Stroke>
          </Line>
        </Canvas>
      </Grid>
    </Paragraph>
  </Section>
</FlowDocument>
```